# How to find the endpoint where this data is being sent to

Tags: python, post, python-requests, google-chrome-devtools, endpoint

im making a python script to practice my skills with requests that basically goes to this link [here](https://footpatrol.s3.amazonaws.com/content/site/2017/FootPatrolRafflePage-adi-bape.html?fullTag=UK_adi_bape_boost?shortTag=UK_bape_boost?prodcutName=adidas-x-Bape-Ultraboost?imgUrl=https://i1.adis.ws/i/jpl/adidas_bape_superbowlliii_social_ig_singles_photography_1080x108013-2-59ff6ae79f6f2ccb6c1121f04038fa62) and keeps entering the raffle over and over again, I looked through the chrome dev tools, and could not find the requests where the data is being sent after I click submit, I don't understand what i'm suppose to do, can someone please explain where to find the post requests where i'm submitting the data to

Comment: Enable "Preserve log" in devtools toolbar, otherwise you won't see the request after the new page loads.

Comment: I think it uses Ajax it something like that, cause when I click submit the button changes to “submitted successfully” and nothing loads

Comment: I’m basically making a python script, to enter that raffle over and over again, but I can’t find the post requests with all he data I send to the forms at all

Comment: i explained it but ok,

Comment: The unclear part is why you expect devtools (a part of the browser) to intercept requests you make in a python script.